# Native library (com/sun/jna/android-aarch64/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path

Tags: java, android, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to work with IBM Watson's Android speech to text library. I noticed there was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621358/com-sun-jna-android-arm-libjnidispatch-so-not-found-in-resource-path) but no answer was given. I have everything integrated but when trying to start the recognize service, it gets this error:

```
                                                                               java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/android-aarch64/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path (.)
                                                                                   at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:786)
                                                                                   at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:746)
                                                                                   at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:135)
                                                                                   at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.<clinit>(NativeLibrary.java:82)
                                                                                   at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:337)
                                                                                   at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.speech_to_text.v1.opus.JNAOpus.<clinit>(JNAOpus.java:42)
                                                                                   at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.speech_to_text.v1.audio.OggOpusEnc.initEncoderWithUploader(OggOpusEnc.java:53)
                                                                                   at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.speech_to_text.v1.audio.WebSocketUploader.initStreamAudioToServer(WebSocketUploader.java:113)
                                                                                   at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.speech_to_text.v1.audio.WebSocketUploader.access$000(WebSocketUploader.java:46)
                                                                                   at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.speech_to_text.v1.audio.WebSocketUploader$2.run(WebSocketUploader.java:175)
07-23 12:51:36.854 27413-27757/com.intellidev.mobitranscribe E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
07-23 12:51:36.874 27413-27757/com.intellidev.mobitranscribe E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
07-23 12:51:36.874 27413-27757/com.intellidev.mobitranscribe E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
07-23 12:51:36.924 27413-27757/com.intellidev.mobitranscribe E/AudioCaptureThread: Error reading voice audio
                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
                                                                                       at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:943)
                                                                                       at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.speech_to_text.v1.audio.AudioCaptureThread.run(AudioCaptureThread.java:62)
```

My code is here:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    txtSpeechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textINput);
    btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //promptSpeechInput();
            //set();
            SpeechToText.sharedInstance().recognize();
        }
    });
    btnEnd = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnEnd);
    btnEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SpeechToText.sharedInstance().stopRecording();

        }
    });


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Configuration
    SpeechConfiguration sConfig = new SpeechConfiguration(SpeechConfiguration.AUDIO_FORMAT_OGGOPUS);
    // STT
    SpeechToText.sharedInstance().initWithContext(this.getHost("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api"), this.getApplicationContext(), sConfig);
    SpeechToText.sharedInstance().setCredentials("PERSONAL","INFO");
    SpeechToText.sharedInstance().setDelegate(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use my code as below, which is gotten from the nuance sample

```
Session session = Session.Factory.session(this, com.intellidev.mobitranscribe.Configuration.SERVER_URI,
                com.intellidev.mobitranscribe.Configuration.APP_KEY);

        Transaction.Options options = new Transaction.Options();
        options.setRecognitionType(RecognitionType.DICTATION);
        options.setDetection(DetectionType.Long);
        options.setLanguage(new Language("ENG-USA"));

        //Start listening
        recoTransaction = speechSession.recognize(options, recoListener);
```